# How do i solve this error in Line xsi:schemalocation

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.6.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.SpringBootMvc</groupId>
    <artifactId>springMVCBoot</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>demoSpringBootMVCWeb</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

error shows "Failure to transfer org.hibernate:hibernate-core:jar:5.4.12.Final from https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates 
 are forced. Original error: Could not transfer artifact org.hibernate:hibernate-core:jar:5.4.12.Final from/to central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): The operation was cancelled. org.eclipse.aether.transfer.ArtifactTransferException: 
 Failure to transfer org.hibernate:hibernate-core:jar:5.4.12.Final from https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates 
 are forced. Original error: Could not transfer artifact org.hibernate:hibernate-core:jar:5.4.12.Final from/to central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): The operation was cancelled. at 
 ..................................................................................................................." on hovering over the line xsi:schemalocation

Comment: try clean install

Comment: Did not solve the problem

Comment: deleted all repositories from .m2 folder (c:/users/username/.m2/repository) and updated maven again, which solved the problem. Thanks @Lemmy

Comment: Hi @Dev can u pls write the steps to update maven...